# Plot Bar chart and Line series chart on separate x-axis in Highcharts out of common dataset

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I got common dataset for both line series and bar graph . In other words dataset consists both line series dataset and bar graph dataset. Now I want to plot line series graph on separate x-axis and bar graph on separate x-axis. And want to control them both from same frame. Like both tooltip for both should come in same popup, from same section I can show and hide them. Attached my screenshot , currently they are sharing same x-axis. I want to separate them. Here is my piece of code.[image]

```
for(j=0; j<timelinejson.length; j++){ 
     seriesOptions[j] = {
            //name: selectedMarkers[i],
            name: timelinejson[j].marker_desc,
            data: mData,

            marker : {
                enabled : true,
                radius : 3
            },
            type : 'spline',
            tooltip : {
                valueDecimals : 2
            }
        };
   }
        seriesOptions[10] = {
            name: 'Speed',
            data: [[1372636800000, 0.16], [1375315200000, 0.36], [1377993600000, 0.4], [1380585600000, 0.68], [1383264000000, 0.6], [1385856000000, 0.64], [1388534400000, 0.68], [1391212800000, 0.69], [1393632000000, 0.71], [1396310400000, 0.73], [1398902400000, 0.74], [1401580800000, 0.75], [1404172800000, 0.76], [1406851200000, 0.17], [1409529600000, 0.67], [1412121600000, 0.18], [1414800000000, 0.58], [1417392000000, 0.28], [1420070400000, 0.58], [1422748800000, 0.49], [1425168000000, 0.39], [1427846400000, 0.29], [1430438400000, 0.59], [1433116800000, 0.19]],

            type: 'column',
            valueDecimals: 1

        };  
drawTrend(seriesOptions,temp)
function drawTrend(marker_array_main,temp) {

  $('#trendChart'+temp).highcharts('StockChart', {

        chart: {
                    height: 400
                    //width: 500    
                },      
                rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 4
                },

                yAxis: {
                    /*labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                        }
                    },*/
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 2,
                        color: 'silver'
                    }]
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    x: 0,
                    y: 100
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> <br/>',
                    valueDecimals: 2
                },

                series: marker_array_main

            });
```

}

Comment: Can you please create a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: As an addition to previous comment, could you also show what would you like to achieve? Would you like to get something similar to this example? http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński that makes perfect sense , very much similar to what I am looking for. Now check this http://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/ctxzvLv9/ if I want to add another bar graph called `Speed` it adds to same axis of `volume`. Can we make it separate.

Comment: Of course, you can separate them in yAxis array: http://jsfiddle.net/ctxzvLv9/1/

Comment: Perfect  @GrzegorzBlachliński , so I can add multiple bar graphs by separating them in yaxis similar way correct ?

Comment: Yes,that is correct. You can add y-axes in your yAxis array and then you can add series to specific yAxis using yAxis: x, where x is the index of axis in yAxis array.

Comment: Perfect post your answer will accept it. One final query can I make the line chart similar to this http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic , that I can show and hide them from right panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can use multiple yAxis in case of your chart. You can add as many yAxes as you want and you can connect your series with this axes using yAxis:x parameter in your Series object.

x value is an index of specific axis in yAxis array.

```
        yAxis: [{
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            },
            height: '60%',
            lineWidth: 2
        }, {
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Volume'
            },
            top: '65%',
            height: '35%',
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        }],


        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Volume',
            data: volume,
            yAxis: 1,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }]
```

Here you can find simple example of this kind of chart from Highcharts demos:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/